# Part identification: 40 tooth gear from The LEGO Movie

Tags: part-identification, gears, the-lego-movie

While watching clip of the LEGO Movie, I found a strange part:

[image: 40t gear]

Slightly earlier in the video, its part number is shown as 3649.

But it doesn't match the 40t gear I know nor the pictures on bricklink.

Is it an error from The LEGO Movie or a variant I don't know?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From this image, you can count the teeth well enough to determine there are actually 60 teeth, not 40:

[image]

This does not appear to be a real part.

It also appears you aren't the first to notice this. Jim Brickkeeper had created [a ShapeWays model](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/371265563026377809/) based on this movie piece which I found while searching for LEGO 60 tooth gears. It's no longer available, but it might be possible to contact them and see if there is another way to get it made.

[According to Matthew Ashton](https://twitter.com/ProfBrickkeeper/status/782730180636835840) this piece was planned for use in the set, but due to budget changes had to be cut, and has not yet been produced.

> For each project we are assigned a certain budget and a certain number of moulds we can create for new pieces. It was our intention with the Movie to make all Characters and Vehicles toys 100%, movie accurate. However in this case the directors really wanted the back wheel to be bigger, so we designed the piece for them, but then later had to make a compromise on one of the models as we didn't have the budget for all the tooling. Lord Business's design had become more complicated and required more moulds than orginally planned.we had to get him 100% correct, so we decided to alter the Super Cycle as we felt it would be less noticeable, at that point we weren't aware that it's part No. would be called out

Comment: Oh, nice. Is it usual in this part of stackexchange to directly mark an answer as answered, or should I wait for more answers ?

Comment: @phi It's up to you.

Comment: The description on shapeways says it was an official unproduced Lego designed element, does anyone have more information on this claim?

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve - it might be better to ask that as a new question, especially as this answer is now accepted ;)

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve I've dug up some info on that and added it to the answer.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara The Shapeways link is broken 

Comment: @mindstormsboi Yeah LEGO has been cracking down on some 3D printed pieces.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara This alternative link can be used for backup. I just used the search engine and found that some guy archived the Shapeways 3D model. https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/371265563026377809/

Comment: @mindstormsboi Yep, that's actually the link I used to replace it,